# How can I change the display of an answer's date to full year?

Tags: support, timestamps, dates

Currently the time stamps under questions or answers in Stack Exchange are displayed as MMM DD YY (e.g. Oct 09'09) when it's more than one year ago, e.g. in profile page:

> [image]

Another example from Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow answer]

This is not native to me, and it really hurts my eyes because I have always to take a closer look to make sense of the most important information - year. How can I change its format to display dates in full year (e.g. Oct 09 2009) instead?

Comment: You'll have to write or install an existing userscript to do that.

Comment: Where does this happen? The tooltip for dates is in YYYY-MM-DD. @ShadowWizard Am I looking in the wrong place??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ not tooltip, the time stamp for posts older than one year, I've added a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ahhh - thanks a lot - I'd never have understood otherwise!!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ lol that's what you got me here for. ;)

Comment: "not native to me" Do you mean not "natural to me"?

Comment: @Peter from what I understand he means that in his country they are using a different date/time format so that format is not "native".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You need to install your own userscript that was either made by you or someone else in Stack Apps. This is no such feature and must implemented via userscript, no exceptions for now. Credit goes to Shadow Wizard for his comment:

> You'll have to write or install an existing userscript to do that.